# R function argument naming. sigm2 = sigm2_prior?

Tags: r

I went through the R documentation and I could not find a clue for this. So the problem is that it seems that l$sigm2 is also assigned when l$sigm2_prior is assigned. Does R behave like this because their similar names? Is there a way go around it?

Function call:

l$sigm2 is not assigned if I change l$sigm2_prior 's name to l$prior.

```
lik_gaussian(lik=lik[[1]],sigm2_prior=pn[[1]], debug=TRUE);
```

**function:**

```
lik_gaussian <-function(...){
l <- list(...);
inputarray <- NULL;
if(!(length(l$lik)==0)){
        inputarray <- c(l$lik); 
    }
if(!(length(l$sigm2)==0)){
                 inputarray <- c(inputarray, l$sigm2); 
    }   
if(!(length(l$sigm2_prior)==0)){
        inputarray <- c(inputarray,l$sigm2_prior); 
    }
print(inputarray);
return(inputarray)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The `'$'` operator uses partial matching. That is, if you evaluate `l$sigm2` it will actually match to `l$sigm2_prior` as well. To use exact matching you need to use `'[['` or and the name of the object as a string:

```
 l[['sigm2_prior']]
```

`'[['` differs from `'$'` in that it has the `exact` argument set to `TRUE` by default. Se also:

```
?'$'
```

Comment: Specifically, see the ?"$" section "Recursive (list-like) objects". Yet another reason to avoid `$` in programming.